# <script> tags not added in response in asp.net core 5 for Web API

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-core, .net-5

I want to handle Error StatusCode in asp.net core.

I wrote this in Startup>Configure

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
            {
                var page = HttpFailedTemplates.NotFoundPage(context.Request.Path,
                        context.TraceIdentifier,
                        DateTime.Now.ToString(),
                        "نیل سافت",
                        "https://localhost:44313/");

                // in page I have -> <script src='https://localhost:44347/js/libraries/jquery.min.js'></script> in <body> tag

                context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
                var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(page);
                using (var stream = context.Response.Body)
                {
                    await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    await stream.FlushAsync();
                }
                await next();
            }
        });
```

**But after return response I don't have Script tags**

Comment: Could you pls share the tutorial you followed to realize your feature?

Comment: I don't have any tutorials. at first I just wanted an simple html string to response, It worked. But when I put the script tag in the string, it did not come out in response. I want write script tags in response body

Comment: HttpFailedTemplates.NotFoundPage is just my html string Generator

Answer (score 0):

> I Added my Script tag in Head tag. Now it work.